# Table-like visualization with label values as row values and column names

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have some metrics from a Prometheus data-source like this (the real data contains many more label combinations):

```
status{pod = "A", platform = "X",} 1
status{pod = "C", platform = "X",} 3
status{pod = "A", platform = "Y",} 5
status{pod = "A", platform = "P",} 8
status{pod = "C", platform = "Y",} 7
status{pod = "B", platform = "Y",} 4
status{pod = "B", platform = "P",} 1
```

For which I need to display the info with a Grafana visualization like this:

|  | X | Y | P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 5 | 8 |
| C | 3 | 7 |  |
| B |  | 4 | 1 |

The labels `pod` and `platform` cannot be hard-coded into the visualization configuration but it needs to be taken from the values from the metrics.

So basically, I need to:

- take the `pod` label values as row values for the first column,
- take the `platform` label values as the column names for the next columns and,
- take the metric values as the intersection between pod and platform as depicted above.

I tried using the [*Table Panel*](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/visualizations/table/) using the [*Labels to fields* transformation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/types-options/#labels-to-fields)  but couldn’t get it working.

So, how could I achieve the described scenario? I’m open to any suggestion that could give me a similar result.

I’d be really thankful for any insights you could provide me with.

<sub>*Posted originally on [Grafana Community](https://community.grafana.com/t/table-like-visualization-with-label-values-as-row-values-and-column-names/42549). Posted here to reach wider audience*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to select the *Time Series* format on the Grafana query editor and then the *Value field name* drop-down is properly populated in the *Transform* tab.

Now I’m able to choose `pod` for that drop-down and the platform values are rendered as column names as expected with their respective values for each pod.